# Drawing a projection on closed convex with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I sollicite your kindness to help me draw  this [image: picture]  of *Theorem of projection on closed convex* , by using the Tikz package.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line connecting `x` and `P_C(x)` has to be normal to `C`. This can be achieved using the `in` and `out` syntax, which is used for almost everything else here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,node contents={}}]
 \draw (0,0) node[bullet,label=left:$P_C(x)$,alias=PC]  -- (15:3) coordinate[midway] (aux)
    node[bullet,label=above right:$x$] -- ++ (-145:4.5) node[midway,below right]{$\|x-z\|$}     node[bullet,label=below left:$z$];
 \draw (PC) to[out=105,in=0] ++ (-0.75,1) to[out=180,in=105] ++ (-1.5,-3)
 node[above right]{$C$} to[out=-75,in=180] ++ (1.25,-1) to[out=0,in=-75] cycle;
 \draw[shorten <=2pt,-latex] (aux) to[out=90,in=-90] ++ (110:0.8) node[above]{$\|x-P_C(x)\|$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]